# Why is capybara feature not able to visit new_user_registration_path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, capybara, fabrication-gem

In my feature spec visit_new_session_path works fine and I can see the login form.
When I use new_user_registration_path it does not work and just shows homepage.
The same issue with `click_link`, `LOG IN` works, `SIGN UP` does not.

I have even tried visit `/users/sign_up` and `/users/sign_in`, sign_in works, sign_up does not. Both routes work using the GUI and show up in rake routes.

```
  visit root_path
  #click_link 'LOG IN'
  visit new_user_session_path
  save_and_open_page
  #click_on 'SIGN UP'
  visit new_user_registration_path
  save_and_open_page
```

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a Data issue.

The seed data differed from the dev data and it was causing the new_user_registration_path to be redirected.